# AllPaintingInWnPaint for TOOL_WINDOW

Tags: vb.net, gdi+

I'm trying to use GDI+ animation in a ToolWindow, whilst keeping the animation flicker-free. When I set the ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint to true the application crashes when the toolwindow is opened.
I create my toolwindow with the following code:

```
SetWindowLong(Handle, win32.GWL.__EXSTYLE, win32.WS._EX_TOOLWINDOW)
```

Where win32 is a class containing all the WM constants from PInvoke. GWL and WS are enums containing the integer values for the respective constants. The SetWindowLong is sourced from a dll import:

```
<DllImport("user32.dll",
EntryPoint:="SetWindowLong")>
Private Shared Function SetWindowLong(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr,
                                     ByVal nIndex As Integer,
                                     ByVal dwNewLong As Integer) As Integer
End Function
```

The ToolWindow code has worked wonderfully for me so far, but I haven't tried to use any GDI animation so far.

Basically, I would appreciate a method to reduce flicker/lag during GDI animation in my toolwindow type form, or a way to use the aforementioned controlstyle. I'm already using these styles:

```
SetStyle(ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer, True)
SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, True)
```

which reduce the flickering by a bit, but not enough.

Comment: Why use `SetWindowLong` at all?  Why not just use `Me.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedToolWindow` or `Me.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.SizableToolWindow` or set the style in the form designer?

Comment: I wanted the form to be borderless, pretty much like a panel control except not  part of the form.

Answer (score -1):

I think I found the problem. In my Form.Paint event I tried to save on typing:

```
Dim g as Graphics = e.Graphics
g.DrawImage(bmp)
```

After changing this back to the original code;

```
e.graphics.DrawImage(bmp)
```

the program worked flawlessly! A lack of understanding on my part regarding variables resulted in many hours wasted.

Comment: There's no reason that code should be the problem.  The `Graphics` class is a reference type so using a variable would make no difference.  The problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: I tried changing it back and it still works, so I guess that wasn't the problem. I have no idea what it could be then, since I only remember changing that part of my code.